# i get "path expected for join" and Query exception: unable to resolve path [Product.ProductID]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two models:

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    @Id
    private String ProductID;

    private String ProductName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Supplier supplier;

    private int quantity;

    private int price;

    //getter setter...
    //constructor...
}


@Entity
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    private String SupplierID;
    private String SupplierName;
    private String Phone;
    private String Address;
    private String Email;

    //getter setter
    //constructor
}
```

In jdbc template of spring i can get all record i want like this:

```
public List<Product> getProducts(int take, int skip){
        List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();

        String sql = "SELECT product.ProductID, product.ProductName, product.Quantity, supplier.SupplierID"
                + ", supplier.SupplierName, product.Price"
                + " FROM product INNER JOIN supplier ON product.SupplierID = supplier.SupplierID"
                + " LIMIT " + skip + "," + take + "";
        list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ProductMapper());

        return list;

public class ProductMapper implements RowMapper<Product> {

    public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int line) throws SQLException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductID(rs.getString("ProductID"));
        product.setProductName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        product.setQuantity(rs.getInt("Quantity"));
        product.setSupplier(new Supplier(rs.getString("SupplierID"), rs.getString("SupplierName")));
        product.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
        return product;
    }
```

But it's wrong in hibernate:

```
//--------hibernate-------
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String queryStr = "SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.ProductName, Product.Quantity, Supplier.SupplierID"
                + ", Supplier.SupplierName, Product.Price"
                + " FROM Product INNER JOIN Supplier ON Product.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID";

        List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);

            query.setFirstResult(skip);
            query.setMaxResults(take);

                list = (List<Product>) query.list();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception e" + e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

i get "path expected for join" and Exception eorg.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [Product.ProductID], unexpected token [Product] [SELECT Product.ProductID .... ]
Anyone can help me to get the same result when i do with jdbc template.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.Quantity, s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName, p.Price
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN p.Supplier s
```

You need to use paths in your HQL query, from one entity to the other. The Hibernate documentation on HQL and joins provides more information here.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: you're welcome, please mark the post answered if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> String sql = "SELECT product.ProductID, product.ProductName,
>   product.Quantity, supplier.SupplierID"
>                   + ", supplier.SupplierName, product.Price"
>                   + " FROM product INNER JOIN supplier ON product.SupplierID = supplier.SupplierID"
>                   + " LIMIT " + skip + "," + take + "";

If you are using sql  query then you need to give SQL table and sql table columns,
But here you are mixing SQL table and Java Classes , like
product is probably a SQL table and Product is the entity class.

So change your query as

```
 String sql = "SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.Quantity, s.SupplierID"
                + ", s.SupplierName, s.Price"
                + " FROM Product p INNER JOIN Supplier s ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID"
                + " LIMIT " + skip + "," + take + "";
```

Also, your variable names are not in camelCase, this can mess up Hibernate's way of mapping a Entity property to table columns, so pay special attention to getter and setters .